# jquery iteration of xml response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml

I have xml respnse from ajax call. I want to iterate it.
Below is my xml ouput in SoaUi.

I want output response as below:

```
50 Water St Oakland USA
101 Emerall New York USA
Sea Point CA USA
```

Please help me to write response in jQuery.

**EDIT:**
This is my response in xml:

```
<ns3:Row>
 <ns3:AddressLine1>50 Water St</ns3:AddressLine1> 
 <ns3:City>Oakland</ns3:City>
 <ns3:Country>USA</ns3:Country>
</ns3:Row>
<ns3:Row>
 <ns3:AddressLine1>101 Emerall</ns3:AddressLine1>
 <ns3:City>New York</ns3:City>
 <ns3:Country>USA</ns3:Country>
</ns3:Row>
<ns3:Row> 
 <ns3:AddressLine1>Sea Point</ns3:AddressLine1>
 <ns3:City>CA</ns3:City>
 <ns3:Country>USA</ns3:Country> 
</ns3:Row>
```

Comment: please update your question with comment information.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the information required looping through the elements and storing the information in a string or whatever you find fit.

One solution (mixing jquery and plain javascript) could be as follows:

```
$(f).each(function (ind, el) {
    var line = '';
    $(el).children().each(function (ind, nod) {
        line += nod.childNodes[0].nodeValue + ' ';
    });
    console.log(line.slice(0, -1));
});
```

the variable 'f' contains the XML string retrieved from the server.

You can test it in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xj5tk56s/2/) (open the developer's console to see the result printed there).

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is here.

```
var geoCompAddress;


$(data).find('ns3\\:Row').each(function() {

geoCompAddress = $(this).find('ns3\\:AddressLine1').text()+ ',' + $(this).find('ns3\\:City').text()+ ',' + $(this).find('ns3\\:Country').text() ;

});
```